# Differences between @+id , @id and @android:id

Tags: android

Differences between?

- @+id/mywidget
- @id/mywidget
- @android:id/mywidget

Comment: Look at the related questions on the right.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html. check the topic id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@+id/mywidget
```

Adds the id to R.java

```
@id/mywidget
```

References an existing id

```
@android:id/mywidget
```

References an id that exists in android.R.java, e.g. resources that are already provided by the framework

Answer (score 4):

---

1. you are declaring a new `id` inside class `R`(from your app)
2. you are referencing and `id` inside class `R` (from your app)
3. you are referencing and `id` inside class `R` (from the `android.R`)

Answer (score 0):

1. @+id/mywidget - you are defining new id mywidget
2. @id/mywidget - you are referencing already defined id mywidget
3. you are referencing an id mywidget from Android